# I am getting "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable object" Deep in XGBoost library functions and can't understand why

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, typeerror, xgboost

I am using XGBoost and attempting to get it to report a custom metric in its built-in cross validation routine (XGB.cv), I am obtaining "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object". I have done what I believe the amalgamation of tutorials on the internet tell me to do in this case, and am wondering if I've found a bug or I'm making a simple mistake somewhere

```
history = xgb.cv(param, dMatrix, num_boost_round=10,as_pandas = True , nfold=5,  custom_metric = myMetric)
```

is calling on my self defined metric function (created to weight precision and recall differently)

```
def myMetric(y_pred , dMatrix):
    y_true = (dMatrix.get_label())

    custom_Score = sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_true,y_pred) * ((2*sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_true,y_pred) - 1)))
    return custom_Score
```

I obtain error stack:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    history = xgb.cv(param, dMatrix, num_boost_round=10,as_pandas = True ,nfold=5,custom_metric = myMetric)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 540, in cv
    should_break = callbacks_container.after_iteration(booster, i, dtrain, None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\callback.py", line 232, in after_iteration
    scores = model.eval(epoch, self.metric, self._output_margin)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 233, in eval
    result = [f.eval(iteration, feval, output_margin) for f in self.cvfolds]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 233, in <listcomp>
    result = [f.eval(iteration, feval, output_margin) for f in self.cvfolds]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.py", line 219, in eval
    return self.bst.eval_set(self.watchlist, iteration, feval, output_margin)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\xgboost\core.py", line 2010, in eval_set
    name, val = feval_ret
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

The source code referenced is (error thrown by last if statements in the function) :

```
    def eval_set(
        self,
        evals: Sequence[Tuple[DMatrix, str]],
        iteration: int = 0,
        feval: Optional[Metric] = None,
        output_margin: bool = True
    ) -> str:
        # pylint: disable=invalid-name
        """Evaluate a set of data.

        Parameters
        ----------
        evals :
            List of items to be evaluated.
        iteration :
            Current iteration.
        feval :
            Custom evaluation function.

        Returns
        -------
        result: str
            Evaluation result string.
        """
        for d in evals:
            if not isinstance(d[0], DMatrix):
                raise TypeError(f"expected DMatrix, got {type(d[0]).__name__}")
            if not isinstance(d[1], str):
                raise TypeError(f"expected string, got {type(d[1]).__name__}")
            self._validate_dmatrix_features(d[0])

        dmats = c_array(ctypes.c_void_p, [d[0].handle for d in evals])
        evnames = c_array(ctypes.c_char_p, [c_str(d[1]) for d in evals])
        msg = ctypes.c_char_p()
        _check_call(
            _LIB.XGBoosterEvalOneIter(
                self.handle,
                ctypes.c_int(iteration),
                dmats,
                evnames,
                c_bst_ulong(len(evals)),
                ctypes.byref(msg),
            )
        )
        assert msg.value is not None
        res = msg.value.decode()  # pylint: disable=no-member
        if feval is not None:
            for dmat, evname in evals:
                feval_ret = feval(
                    self.predict(dmat, training=False, output_margin=output_margin), dmat
                )
                if isinstance(feval_ret, list):
                    for name, val in feval_ret:
                        # pylint: disable=consider-using-f-string
                        res += "\t%s-%s:%f" % (evname, name, val)
                else:
                    name, val = feval_ret
                    # pylint: disable=consider-using-f-string
                    res += "\t%s-%s:%f" % (evname, name, val)
        return res
```

Can you see the problem? Is it on my end?

I've also tried converting everything into type int in myMetric (just to see) and i receive "cannot unpack non-iterable type int"

information for CV function can be found at
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html
Here is the followup for using custom metrics
https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/custom_metric_obj.html

Answer (score 0):

I was lying to all you kind people... answer was 'simple' and it was in the documentation, should return a string + an output value! and do this line in the definition to be safe... make it look like the doc

Looks like:

```
def myMetric(y_pred , dMatrix)  -> Tuple[str,float]:
y_true = (dMatrix.get_label())

custom_Score = sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_true,y_pred) * ((2*sklearn.metrics.precision_score(y_true,y_pred) - 1)))
return "CustomScore", custom_Score #cannot be spaces in this string
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).